# Where does responsibility lie when creating inheritance map from dynamic construct

Tags: c#, dynamic, architecture, solid-principles

Hi when compiling a structure of inheritance from different sources should distinct graphs be created by each of the sources and then attempt to combine or something different?

What I need to achieve, an object definition:

- Workers

  - Worker

    - Name
    - Position
- Clients

  - Client

    - Name
    - Questionnaires

      - Customer Satisfaction Questionnare

        - Where you happy?
      - Exit Questionnaire

        - Why are you leaving?
- Questionnaires

The context, all questionnaire information / property definitions come from a stored procedure which pivots information in rows of a database

All properties for clients & workers - name, position etc come from object first entity framework entities

The system has to be generic where the existence of questionnaires may change in different deployments and entities could be different

I thought if a provider responsible for questionnaires is loaded and given an inheritance 'template' it has the responsibility of putting questionnaire properties for 'exit questionnaire' under 'clients' in its own graph if it matches some identifier on the questionnaire and if no matches are found making the decision to add to generic questionnaires.

Then the distinct graphs are combined and that which is responsible for combining handles the process.

Is this at all correct?

Comment: I don't think you are using terminology correctly. What is an "inheritance map"? And what exactly do you mean by graph? I also don't follow the meaning of the "object definition" indented bullet points.

Comment: Yes I think I'm getting myself confused along the way. I'm responsible for creating a system capable of supplying a class object which another application will then reflect over, and display all available properties in a tree.

Comment: Do you have some working example code? It's really hard to get it properly without some instrumentation...